# Authorship disagreement between PhD student and supervisor

Tags: phd, thesis, journals, paper-submission, authorship

I completed my PhD thesis two years ago. My thesis subject was supported as a project by my university scientific research committee. In this project my supervisor was principal investigator and I was co-investigator. After finishing my thesis, I cannot get along with my supervisor due to personal reasons.

I have to write an article from my PhD thesis according to the academic progress requirements in my country. I have already written a manuscript from my thesis and added my supervisor name as an author.

In many interviews with him, he said that he did not want to be a coauthor. However, he does not provide me with a signed document stating that he does not want to be a coauthor. It is obligatory to obtain a signed document of the author who does not want to be included in the manuscript as an author in my country.

If I do not add his name in the manuscript, I will be faced with plagiarism. If I add it, my supervisor can contact the journal to withdraw the manuscript after it is published. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: It seems like your country has peculiar enough rules that you will need to identify it to get useful answers.

Comment: Have you tried simply sending an email to ask if they want to be an author? That would provide a written (albeit easy to fake) confirmation, would that be enough for your country's rules?

Comment: strange that if you completed your degree there are still academic requirements.

Comment: *"It is obligatory to obtain a signed document of the author who does not want to be included in the manuscript as an author"* This seems to be circular. Could you please clarfiy what precisely this rule says and to which situations it applies?

Comment: Specifically, who is actually asking for this document? The journal won't care.

Comment: Just give us a photo or screenshot of the "rule" in its exact expression. Seems very strange.